# The autocompletion and Inspect is not working in spyder python

Tags: python, autocomplete, spyder

I am using windows 8.1, with python 3.5 64 bit on anaconda spyder. I can't able to access the help and autocompletion. I have checked in preference also all the settings are right. I could not able to figure out. I have jedi 0.10.2 package also which is for autocompletion.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to uninstall enum34 by using the command:

```
pip uninstall enum34
```

If you do this directly from your command window (cmd), it won't work. To make this work, you have to activate your Python environment from which you wish to delete the package.

So the steps are as follows: 
1. Press Windows+R
2. Type `activate your_env_name`
3. Type `pip uninstall enum34`

P.S. In case you get an error like 'activate is not recognized as ....', just add your Anaconda3>Scripts path to the System Paths.